# Querying panda DataFrame column to the main datasource

Tags: python, pandas

Hi Guys I'm new to python and I want to learn how to query a data column to my data source.

this is my panda dataframe

```
[In] top10_athletes = athletes.head(10)
     top10_athletes = top10_athletes.rename(columns={'index': 'Name', 'Name': 'Medal Count'})
     top10_athletes.index = np.arange(1,len(top10_athletes)+1)
     top10_athletes
[Out]
                Name                         Medal Count
1   Michael Fred Phelps, II                      28
2   Larysa Semenivna Latynina (Diriy-)           18
3   Nikolay Yefimovich Andrianov                 15
4   Ole Einar Bjrndalen                          13
5   Borys Anfiyanovych Shakhlin                  13
6   Edoardo Mangiarotti                          13
7   Takashi Ono                                  13
8   Birgit Fischer-Schmidt                       12
9   Paavo Johannes Nurmi                         12
10  Sawao Kato                                   12
```

I want to query all the values in the Name column into my main data source
the only way that I could think of is this piece of code I tried searching in Google

```
df.query("Name == 'Michael Fred Phelps, II'")
```

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

To query by **Name** column you can use the following:

```
df[df["Name"] == 'Michael Fred Phelps, II')
```